# Deploy Visual Basic application without registering DLLs?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2013, dll

I've built a simple application in visual basic ( Visual Studio 2013 ). My application uses some DLLs that are also created by me in C++. 
I've tried to run the release *.exe on another PC ( the folder contains the exe and all the DLLs )  and it's not working because the DLLs are not found.

The exact error is: 
 `Class not registered ( Exception from HRESULT:0x80040154 ( REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))`

My question is, how can I run my application on other PCs without registering the DLLs ? I don't have administrator rights on the PCs where I'm trying to run the application.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your reply. The error is : `Class not registered ( Exception from HRESULT:0x80040154 ( REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) `. If I register all the DLLs, the exe is working. If the DLLs are not registered, the exe returns that error.

Comment: Why is this info not in the question???  If you don't tell us what you know then you'll never get a usable answer.  This should be obvious.

Comment: Given that you are using Visual Studio 2013, a simple answer could be "don't use COM" - but that may not help. I'm not sure what the syntax or annotations would be in the assembly, but you can investigate using "per user" registration; the "per user" registration generally requires fewer permissions to be registered for that user (but then only that user).